# Use envdir to set environment variables in running process

Tags: daemontools

I have a directory with a list of files containing environment variables; for example a file named REALM that has the contents "dev", a file named TZ that has the contents "UTC", etc.

I'd like to set these in the current process environment, for example as part of `.bash_profile`. A tool exists to do this - [`envdir`](http://thedjbway.b0llix.net/daemontools/envdir.html) - however that's normally used when starting a subprocess.

Is there a good way to do this? At the moment I'm checking whether they are set in the `.bash_profile` and calling `exec envdir /path/to/env bash` if they are not set, though that seems hacky and risks a recursive loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha, just eval the results of running env.

```
eval "$(env -i envdir /etc/meter-environment.d env)"
```